# How to read SSAS trace file without profiler?

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have been having difficulties to open the traces (.trc files) using the function fn_trace_gettable.(File 'C:\OLAP_TRACE2.trc' is not a recognizable trace file.) The traces being generated are from SSAS cubes and I have no diffculty to open it in SQL Server Profiler. I have bunch of trace files and I can’t just sit and load each one of the traces into a table separately. I need to automate this and thus want to write a package/code to avoid this.

Comment: Have the same issue here. i'm trying to parse/read the trace file from SSAS using powershell but to no avail. Did you solve  your problem in this?

Comment: Yeah, try extended events. Its great!